# Grouping table rows and joining the results to another table

Tags: sql-server-2005, join

I have these three tables:

**Table 1 :**

```
    InvoiceId         InvoiceNumber        CompanyId
    -------------------------------------------------
       3                   1                  2
       4                   2                  2
       6                   1                  1
       7                   3                  2
       8                   4                  2
       9                   2                  1
```

**Table 2 :**

```
    CompanyId          CompanyName
    -------------------------------
       1                  Name1
       2                  Name2
```

**Tabel 3 :**

```
    InvoiceId        AcceptDate       AcceptType
    ---------------------------------------------
       3                AAAA               O
       3                BBBB               P
       6                CCCC               P
       4                DDDD               O
       7                EEEE               O
       9                FFFF               P
       7                GGGG               P
```

*Tables 1 and 3 have a one-to-many relationship, with Table 3 having the multiple linked rows. Table 3 will have a maximum of 2 rows per InvoiceId.*

**Task**

I want to group Table 3 rows to give this result:

```
    InvoiceId       AcceptDate1      AcceptDate2
    --------------------------------------------
        3              AAAA             BBBB
        6              CCCC             null
        4              DDDD             null
      and ....
```

And then join those results with Table 1 and Table 2 to give:

```
    InvoiceId     InvoiceNumber        AcceptDate1    AcceptDate2      Name
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------
       3               1                  AAAA           BBBB          Name2
       4               2                  DDDD           null          Name2
       7               3                  EEEE           GGGG          Name2
       8               4                  null           null          Name2
       6               1                  CCCC           null          Name1
       9               2                  FFFF           null          Name1
```

AcceptDate1 and AcceptDate2 is static.

Comment: I need an new table that merge AcceptDate of each InvoiceId from Table3 in one row, then join this new table with two other tables. I need a query on Table3 that create a new table with this Column : InvoiceId, AcceptDate1, AcceptDate2. If an invoiceId had only one record in table3, only AcceptDate1 fills and AcceptDate2 is null. I can't explain good in english. SORRY

Comment: @MichaelBuen thanks for that informative link!

Comment: @Behnam I understand what you want, can you tell us which AcceptDate from Table 3 to select, for which AcceptType?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is to [Pivot the data](http://www.tsqltutorials.com/pivot.php).

```
BEGIN TRAN

create table #table1 (InvoiceId int, InvoiceNumber int, CompanyId int)
create table #table2 (CompanyId int, CompanyName varchar(50))
create table #table3 (InvoiceId int, AcceptDate datetime, AcceptType char(1))
insert into #table1 values (3, 1, 2)
insert into #table1 values (4, 2, 2)
insert into #table1 values (6, 1, 1)
insert into #table1 values (7, 3, 2)
insert into #table1 values (8, 4, 2)
insert into #table1 values (9, 2, 1)
insert into #table2 values (1, 'Name1')
insert into #table2 values (2, 'Name2')
insert into #table3 values (3, '2012-01-01', 'o')
insert into #table3 values (3, '2012-01-02', 'p')
insert into #table3 values (6, '2012-01-03', 'p')
insert into #table3 values (4, '2012-01-04', 'o')
insert into #table3 values (7, '2012-01-05', 'o')
insert into #table3 values (9, '2012-01-06', 'p')
insert into #table3 values (7, '2012-01-07', 'p')

SELECT #table1.InvoiceId, #table1.InvoiceNumber, t.o as [AcceptDate1], t.p as [AcceptDate2], #table2.CompanyName
FROM #table3 pivot (max(AcceptDate) for AcceptType IN ("o", "p")) as t
JOIN #table1 on #table1.InvoiceId = t.InvoiceId
JOIN #table2 on #table2.CompanyId = #table1.CompanyId

ROLLBACK
```

This gives:

```
InvoiceId   InvoiceNumber AcceptDate1             AcceptDate2             CompanyName
----------- ------------- ----------------------- ----------------------- --------------------------------------------------
3           1             2012-01-01 00:00:00.000 2012-01-02 00:00:00.000 Name2
4           2             2012-01-04 00:00:00.000 NULL                    Name2
6           1             NULL                    2012-01-03 00:00:00.000 Name1
7           3             2012-01-05 00:00:00.000 2012-01-07 00:00:00.000 Name2
9           2             NULL                    2012-01-06 00:00:00.000 Name1

(5 row(s) affected)
```